# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '01HP011' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql, where-clause

I am getting conversion error on one server but not other server, both got same database, one is test and other one is live, test is actually copy of live but slightly old. Live server has AlwaysOn enabled.
when i ran Print @@version on both server, i get following

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU1) (KB3208177) - 13.0.4411.0 (X64) 
    Jan  6 2017 14:24:37 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
```

This is the sql query i am running

```
exec sp_executesql N'select * From DataTable
WHERE DT1 = @P1 AND DT2 = @P2
order by
cp1',N'@P1 smallint,@P2 smallint',0,0
```

column DT2 has mix value of 1 and 1BAC and NULL but i don't understand why it works on one server but not other.

Comment: Your types really have to match, for all sorts of reasons. If DT2 is not a smallint, why are you using a smallint in your WHERE clause? That's just broken.

Comment: Thanks, code is written in the app and it's sending request like that but it is failing to run against live but work on test and the only difference is test is slightly older than Live and sitting on different server, 90% of data in that table matches, so why it works on test ?

Comment: To make an obvious statement, but the error *is* telling you the problem here, `'01HP011'` isn't a valid `int` value. `int`s don't have letters in them.

Comment: Thanks Larun, i kind of guessed what error is saying but my question remains the same, why it works on one but not the other...

Comment: Why does it work in one and not the other. First we must assume that what you claim is true - that the databases are identical in structure. We know that they don't have the same content, which is a factor. But even assuming they did, LUCK is why it works on one and not on another. Your code relies on an unsafe implicit conversion. In the lucky case, the execution plan avoids the rows that cannot be converted. Why does it do that? Compare the plans and compare the rows accessed.

Comment: And even if you know why, what then? Your application code needs to be fixed - avoidance of a bug is not a winning strategy.

Comment: According to the rules for [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) when you combine a `SmallInt` and a string data type in an expression, e.g. `DT2 = @P2`, the string will be converted to a `SmallInt`. You could use `Cast` to force the conversion the other way, e.g. `DT2 = Cast( @P2 as VarChar(10) )`.

Comment: Thanks guys, when i find out that it works on database which has same structure but less data then i thought it might be some sort of database/server level setting which might be causing this issue, that's why i turn to you guys... Thanks again

Comment: Tip: You can use [`Try_Convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to identify the "bad" values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks lke `dt2` is defined as a string, not as a number. You should align the datatype of your parameter to the correct datatype - otherwise SQL Server attemps to coerce the string to a number, which fails on a value like `'1ABC'`:

Consider:

```sql
exec sp_executesql 
    N'select * From DataTable WHERE DT1 = @P1 AND DT2 = @P2 order by cp1',
    N'@P1 smallint, @P2 nvarchar(10)', 0, '0'
```

You might want to review the size of the parameter string, and make sure that the other parameter does not have the same kind of problem.

---

Why your code fails on one server but not on the other is most likely related to your data: either all values in `dt2` are convertible to a number, or mabye the other `where` predicate eliminates the "wrong" values before the server tries to convert them.

Here is [a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=33fbcd5830bad113d8ccf6007b647003) that demonstrates this.

Sample data:

```
dt1 | dt2  |  cp1
--: | :--- | ---:
  0 | 1    | null
  0 | 1ABC | null
  0 | null | null
```

This fails with a conversion error:

```
exec sp_executesql 
    N'select * From DataTable WHERE DT1 = @P1 AND DT2 = @P2 order by cp1',
    N'@P1 int, @P2 int', 0, 10
```

This works (and return an empty resultset):

```
exec sp_executesql 
    N'select * From DataTable WHERE DT1 = @P1 AND DT2 = @P2 order by cp1',
    N'@P1 int, @P2 int', 1, 10
```

Comment: Test is a month old and has also got mix data(number, string), is there a database/server level setting which might be forcing sql server to behave differently? Also to add, `Where` condition is same on both server. not sure why app code is written like this but all i am tryng to find, why it works. also Where condition is always same with same value, 0 , 0 and top 1000 rows on that table are same. they way code is written, it always return 0 rows